# Find bus number and device number with device file symlink

Tags: c++, c, linux, device

I have a device file(`SYMLINK`) `/dev/CDMAModem` generated by a `udev` rule. I want to find the bus number and device number of the actual device. Actually I want to perform `USBDEVFS_RESET` ioctl on device `/dev/bus/usb/BUS_NO/DEVICE_NO` in my C++ program.

----udev rule----

```
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="zte_ev", ATTRS{bNumEndpoints}=="03", SYMLINK+="CDMAModem"
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ACTION=="remove", DRIVERS=="zte_ev", ATTRS{bNumEndpoints}=="03", SYMLINK-="CDMAModem"
```

Answer (score 5):

I think libudev will give you that:

```
#include <libudev.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    struct udev *udev;
    struct udev_enumerate *enumerate;
    struct udev_list_entry *devices, *dev_list_entry;
    struct udev_device *dev;

    udev = udev_new();

    enumerate = udev_enumerate_new(udev);
    udev_enumerate_add_match_subsystem(enumerate, "CDMAModem");
    udev_enumerate_scan_devices(enumerate);
    devices = udev_enumerate_get_list_entry(enumerate);

    udev_list_entry_foreach(dev_list_entry, devices) {
        const char *path;
    
        path = udev_list_entry_get_name(dev_list_entry);
        dev = udev_device_new_from_syspath(udev, path);

        fprintf(stderr, "devnum: %s\n",
            udev_device_get_sysattr_value(dev, "devnum"));
        fprintf(stderr, "busnum: %s\n",
            udev_device_get_sysattr_value(dev, 'busnum:));
        udev_device_unref(dev);
    }

    udev_enumerate_unref(enumerate);
    udev_unref(udev);

    return 0;
}
```

You can then use this information with ioctl() as in:

```
[charles@localhost 2-1]$ cd /sys/class/mem/random
[charles@localhost 2-1]$echo $PWD
/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:11.0/0000:02:00.0/usb2/2-1
```

Comment: its looking promising i will execute it tomorrow. Thanq!

Comment: I left out a couple of details, but this default case should lead us in the right direction.

Comment: `udev_enumerate_get_list_entry(enumerate)` returned `NULL`. I also tried `"/dev/CDMAModem"` and `"/dev/ttyUSB0"`; did'nt work. `udevadm info -a -p $(sudo udevadm info -q path -n /dev/ttyUSB0)` is giving bus and device number so definitely I should use `libudev`. +1

Comment: Do you get a valid udev struct from the udev_new() call? If so try calling `udev_enumerate_add_match_subsystem(enumerate, "usb")` or `udev_enumerate_add_match_subsystem(enumerate, "usb_device")`or using the appropriate CDMAModem `/sys/class` entry.

Comment: yes I got udev struct in all cases. `"usb"` gave all usb devices connected; http://justpaste.it/drjb is the output. But I need to find bus and device no. of `/dev/CDMAModem`.

Comment: Now it became obvious to me to use `libudev` as the `SYMLINK` is generated by `udev`.

Comment: We need to find what `/sys/class` entry contains your device: `net`? Can you recursively check? It looks like you'll get the bus and device number as in `usb` above. Although I don't know how to find the correct class - can someone advise?

Comment: `find /sys/class/ -name ttyUSB0` gave
`/sys/class/tty/ttyUSB0` so device is of `tty` class. `find` with `CDMAModem` didn't give any result. `net` class only had `eth0` and `l0`. I've disabled ModemManager; It may be the reason why `net` class don have the device.

Comment: yeah got it!! `udev_enumerate_add_match_subsystem(enumerate, "tty");` should give the result :D

Comment: Does `find /sys -name CMDAModem` give anything?

Answer (score 2):

You can perform an `ioctl` on the file represented by the symlink `/dev/CDMAModem` as you would on the file under the `/dev/bus/` structure.

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <linux/usbdevice_fs.h>

int f = open("/dev/CDMAModem", O_RDWR);
ioctl(f, USBDEVFS_RESET);
```

If you actually want to find where this link is pointing, the `file` command will tell you.

```
> file /dev/CDMAModem
/dev/CDMAModem: symbolic link to `bus/usb/BUS/DEV'
```

Comment: nop u can't do that! `/dev/CDMAModem` is not symbolic link of `bus/usb/BUS/DEV`

Comment: You said the file was created by a udev rule (presumably written by you), which usually produces symlinks.  Since clearly that's not the case, could you post the udev file, or at least the output of the `file` command?

Comment: i tried doing ioctl on `/dev/CDMAModem` in first which lead to post this question. I updated the question with `udev` rule.

Comment: `file /dev/CDMAModem
/dev/CDMAModem: symbolic link to ttyUSB0` and `file /dev/ttyUSB0
/dev/ttyUSB0: character special`

Answer (score 1):

I think the `stat()` library call would be a good place to start... Along with libusb.

Comment: Using `stat()` will follow the symlink(s) to the device (or file) at the end and report the information from there. The chances are that the major and minor device number encode the information needed.

Comment: definitely I should at least use `libusb` as `/dev/CDMAModem` is a `SYMLINK` of inode created by the modem driver. I will put a bounty on this tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to do is resolve the link, you can use [readlink](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Symbolic-Links.html) and parse the information later with string functions.

> Function: ssize_t readlink (const char *filename, char *buffer, size_t size)
>
> The readlink function gets the value of the symbolic link filename. The file name that the link points to is copied into buffer. This file name string is not null-terminated; readlink normally returns the number of characters copied. The size argument specifies the maximum number of characters to copy, usually the allocation size of buffer.

Answer (score 1):

```
~$ sudo udevadm info -a -p $(sudo udevadm info -q path -n /dev/CDMAModem)
[sudo] password for gowtham:

Udevadm info starts with the device specified by the devpath and then
walks up the chain of parent devices. It prints for every device
found, all possible attributes in the udev rules key format.
A rule to match, can be composed by the attributes of the device
and the attributes from one single parent device.

  looking at device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2:1.0/ttyUSB0/tty/ttyUSB0':
    KERNEL=="ttyUSB0"
    SUBSYSTEM=="tty"
    DRIVER==""

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2:1.0/ttyUSB0':
    KERNELS=="ttyUSB0"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb-serial"
    DRIVERS=="zte_ev"
    ATTRS{port_number}=="0"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2:1.0':
    KERNELS=="2-1.2:1.0"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="zte_ev"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceClass}=="ff"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceSubClass}=="ff"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceProtocol}=="ff"
    ATTRS{bNumEndpoints}=="03"
    ATTRS{supports_autosuspend}=="1"
    ATTRS{bAlternateSetting}==" 0"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceNumber}=="00"
    ATTRS{interface}=="Data Interface"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2':
    KERNELS=="2-1.2"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="usb"
    ATTRS{bDeviceSubClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{bDeviceProtocol}=="00"
    ATTRS{devpath}=="1.2"
    ATTRS{idVendor}=="19d2"
    ATTRS{speed}=="12"
    ATTRS{bNumInterfaces}==" 6"
    ATTRS{bConfigurationValue}=="1"
    ATTRS{bMaxPacketSize0}=="64"
    ATTRS{busnum}=="2"
    ATTRS{devnum}=="8"
```

> ```
>   ATTRS{busnum}=="2"
>   ATTRS{devnum}=="8"
> ```

Though this is ugly but works. From C++ program call `udevadm` and filter for `busnum` and `devnum` attributes from the output. I hope some developer who involved in `libudev` development shall help and may be `udev` mailing-list will help.