# libudev get devnum for specific tty in C

Tags: c, linux, udev

I want to get `devnum` for a specific tty e.g. `/dev/ttyUSB1`. To do so I modified the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/20341112/2429333 as follows:

```
int get_devnum(const char *filename)
{
    if( filename == NULL) return -1;

    int retval;
    const char *path;
    const char *sysattr;
    struct udev *udev;
    struct udev_enumerate *enumerate;
    struct udev_list_entry *devices, *dev_list_entry;
    struct udev_device *dev;

    retval = -1;

    udev = udev_new();

    enumerate = udev_enumerate_new(udev);
    udev_enumerate_add_match_subsystem(enumerate, "tty");
    udev_enumerate_scan_devices(enumerate);
    devices = udev_enumerate_get_list_entry(enumerate);

    udev_list_entry_foreach(dev_list_entry, devices) {

        path = udev_list_entry_get_name(dev_list_entry);
        dev = udev_device_new_from_syspath(udev, path);

        if(strcmp(udev_device_get_devnode(dev), filename) == 0)
        {
            dev = udev_device_get_parent_with_subsystem_devtype(
                    dev,
                    "usb",
                    "usb_device");
            sysattr = udev_device_get_sysattr_value(dev, "devnum");
            if(sysattr != NULL)
            {
                retval = strtol(sysattr, NULL, 10);
            }
            udev_device_unref(dev);
            break;
        }
        udev_device_unref(dev);
    }

    udev_enumerate_unref(enumerate);
    udev_unref(udev);

    return retval;
}
```

What I don't like about this solution is that I have to iterate over all those list entries in a specific subsystem. Is there a way I can use devnode information (filename) to get the `portnum` with libudev?

Answer (score 0):

Devices which present a "traditional" file I/O style interface to user space can be uniquely identified (for historical reasons) using a combination of their devnum (composed of major+minor number), and type (character or block).

A libudev `device` can be created by calling `udev_device_new_from_devnum()` with the type and devnum as parameters.

Given a filesystem path to the device, you can use one of the c library `stat()` family of calls to discover the type and devnum.

The devnum you need will be in the `st_rdev` member of the `stat` struct.

The type can be inferred from the contents of the `st_mode` member.  Check if `st_mode & S_IFMT` is equal to `S_ISCHR` or `S_ISBLK` respectively.  Based on this test result, pass either `'c'` or `'b'` as the type argument.