# C/C++ How to get the usb subsystem path for a USB libudev hidraw device?

Tags: c++, linux, usb

I'm using libudev in C/C++ with the hidraw subsystem to enumerate and communicate with custom HID devices - working well. My devices are assigned specific usb plugs and they are "hot swappable" - I need to know which plug is connected to each hidraw device. Is there a correspondence between the usb and the hidraw subsystems and how to get the usb path which details the interface route (**like: /dev/bus/usb/002/001** and not the hidraw path) for each device **from its hidraw device pointer?**

Comment: BTW I duplicated the calls with subsystem "usb" and I can get paths like "usb2/2-2/2-2:1.0" but these paths presist no matter wher I plug the device - in other words they do not point to the specific plug of the usb hub.

Answer (score 1):

i think with hidraw device pointer you mean the device nodes like `/dev/hidraw0` or similar

> Hidraw uses a dynamic major number, meaning that udev should be relied
>   on to create hidraw device nodes.  Udev will typically create the
>   **device nodes** directly under /dev (eg: /dev/hidraw0).  As this location
>   is distribution- and udev rule-dependent, applications should use
>   libudev to locate hidraw devices attached to the system.  There is a
>   tutorial on libudev with a working example at:
>     http://www.signal11.us/oss/udev/

linux has two species of device nodes, one created by device drivers i.e. `/dev/sdb` for a mass storage device and raw device nodes like `/dev/bus/usb/BBB/DDD` where `BBB` is the bus number and `DDD` is the device number, that are created by the kernel directly :

> **USB Device Issues**
>
> USB devices usually have **two kinds of device nodes** associated with
>   them.
>
> The **first kind is created by device-specific drivers** (e.g.,
>   usb_storage/sd_mod or usblp) in the kernel. For example, a USB mass
>   storage device would be /dev/sdb, and a USB printer would be
>   /dev/usb/lp0. These device nodes exist only when the device-specific
>   driver is loaded.
>
> The **second kind of device nodes (/dev/bus/usb/BBB/DDD, where BBB is
>   the bus number and DDD is the device number) are created even if the
>   device doesn't have a kernel driver. By using these "raw" USB device
>   nodes**, an application can exchange arbitrary USB packets with the
>   device, i.e., bypass the possibly-existing kernel driver.

source : http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/7.10/postlfs/devices.html

you want to establish a link between the kernel module device node ( i.e. `/dev/hidraw0` )  and the corresponding raw device node ( i.e `/dev/bus/usb/BBB/DDD` )

you can get the bus address (`BBB` and `DDD` ) from the device node using  `sudo udevadm info -a -p $(sudo udevadm info -q path -n /dev/hidraw0)` ( `ATTRS{busnum}=="BBB"` and `ATTRS{devnum}=="DDD"` in the output ) however this is a bit ugly

in [Find bus number and device number with device file symlink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20249418/find-bus-number-and-device-number-with-device-file-symlink) is code using `libudev` to get bus number BBB and device number DDD for a specific device node in `/dev/` i.e. `/dev/hidraw0` it uses `udev_device_get_sysattr_value(dev, "devnum"));` to get `DDD` in `/dev/bus/usb/BBB/DDD` and `udev_device_get_sysattr_value(dev, busnum"));` to get `BBB`

you can also get BBB and DDD from `sysfs` ( `/sys/devices/ ...` ) :

> `/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:12.2/usb2/2-5/2-5.4$ ls 2-5.4:1.0`
>   bDeviceSubClass     configuration  idProduct     remove authorized
>   bmAttributes        descriptors    idVendor      serial 
>   avoid_reset_quirk    bMaxPacketSize0     dev            manufacturer
>   speed bcdDevice            bMaxPower           **devnum**
>   maxchild  subsystem bConfigurationValue  bNumConfigurations  devpath
>   power         uevent bDeviceClass         bNumInterfaces      driver
>   product       urbnum bDeviceProtocol      **busnum**
>   ep_00
>
> quirks version

source : http://www.signal11.us/oss/udev/

to get the sysfs path of your device ( the `/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:12.2/usb2/2-5/2-5.4` above ) use `sudo udevadm info -q path -n /dev/hidraw0`

( https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/344784/how-to-map-sys-bus-usb-devices-to-dev-video )

Comment: Thanks Ralf, for your complete description of the USB registration in the linux system. I know about the device path - and it is unique in a sense because the same device reconnected gets a new device number in the path string. However the path does not identify specific connector in the USB hub. If I connect a USB device to two different ports of the hub I get the same exact path excluding an instance number which increments every time the device is connected. What I need is a specific identifier for each port of the HUB so that it is possible to associate a USB device with a port.

Answer (score 0):

Hope it's helpful but IIRC, you cannot reliably (with port# being same between insert events) enumerate individual ports on hubs that are connected downstream from a main USB controller point. I think that was one of the reasons we started seeing lots and lots of USB controllers on MB's after USB came out; because when chaining everything off downstream hubs, besides negatively affecting bandwidth, also caused problems with persistent software numbering issues.

I believe when a device is plugged into a USB port directly connected to a USB controller, you can reliably get the same exact port# it's connected to. But when doing that from a downstream multi-port USB hub connected upstream to a USB port from a USB controller, the actual port# on the USB hub does not get passed upstream or even if it does, it is not a predictable port# between insertions/power-resets in the same hub port.